# Ruby-on-Rails: Devise custom failure app problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to set up Devise to return 401 to unauthorized API requests instead of redirects but I'm running into a boulder. This is how I am overriding it's custom failure behavior:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
    include ActionController::Head
    include ActionController::MimeResponds

    def respond
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {
                super
            }
            format.any { head :status => 401}
        end
    end
end
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `lookup_context' for #<CustomFailure:0x000001031f6220>
```

and it points to the `respond_to do |format|` line

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def respond
  unless request.format.to_sym == :html
    http_auth
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Devise::FailureApp is inherited form ActionController::Metal which is interacting with Rack on low level, so there is no respond_to view related stuff